# How to do a Sending Time Optimization Model

Tags: machine-learning, business-intelligence, modeling

I have a question about optimizing the message (email/push/text etc.) sending time to our subscribers. The desired output will be a time interval of each day for each person.

We have the history of the time when a person opened/clicked our message, their demographic information and some other browsing history. But I am not sure if this could be a machine learning model since each individual behaved so differently and I don't have many good predictors.

Should I just summarize the best reaching time for them in the historical data, or it could be a machine learning model?

Comment: hey, did you arrive at any  conclusion ?